# Is it possible to replace the windows explorer context menu with something other than a menu?

Tags: windows, contextmenu, explorer, windows-explorer

I would like to write an application/extension that would replace the default explorer right-click context menu with something other than a menu, preferably a custom window. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Please don't do this.  People have expectations of how the shell works.  If I installed your software and it did this, I would immediately uninstall it and never trust you again.

Comment: @Luke: What if the entire point of my program is to do exactly this?

Comment: Just because you want to do something doesn't mean it is a good idea to do it.  Believe me, I have plenty of experience.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but implementing a shell extension that subclasses the explorer window seems like the way to go. The following CodeProject article talks about a shell extension with a keyboard hook. It should be possible to adapt this to intercept the mouse and WM_CONTEXT messages:

> **[Shell Extension with Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/smartmove.aspx)**